# Serialization of POJOs with biderectional relationship to JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have 2 POJOs with one-to-many relationship:

**Receipt.java**

```
@Entity   
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="receiptId")
public class Receipt implements Serializable {    

    private long receiptId;        
    private int receiptNumber;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiptid")
    private List<Sales> sales;

//getters and setters
}
```

**Sales.java**

```
@Entity    
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "salesId")
public class Sales implements Serializable {

    private long salesId;
    private String salesProduct;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiptid", nullable = false)
    private Receipt receipt;

//getters and setters
}
```

I have 2 simple queries. The first one must return Receipts and their Sales and the second one must return Sale and their Receipt. If I use @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference annotations, then only one query works correctly.

When I use @JsonIdentityInfo annotation I get serialized JSONs with a unnecessary plain id numbers. Like a number 122 at the end of this JSON:

```
[{"receiptId":122,
"receiptNumber":2,
"sales":[{
    "salesId":2,
    "salesProduct":"product1"
    ,"receipt":122},
    {
    "salesId":4,
    "salesProduct":"product2"
    ,"receipt":122}]},
122]
```

And a number 4 at the end of this JSON:

```
[{"salesId":2,
"salesProduct":"product1",
"receipt":
   {"receiptId":122,
   "receiptNumber":2,
   "sales":[
        2,
        {"salesId":4,
         "receipt":122,
         "salesProduct":"product2",
        }]
    }
},
4]
```

What do I have to do to get correct JSONs from the server?

Thanks

**Update 1:**
Expected JSON:

```
[{
"salesId":2,
"salesProduct":"product1",
"receipt":
   {"receiptId":122,
   "receiptNumber":2,
   "sales":[2,4]
    }
},
{"salesId":4,     
"salesProduct":"product2"
"receipt":
   {"receiptId":122,
   "receiptNumber":2,
   "sales":[2,4]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Get rid of code not relevant to the question (JPA attrs), and shorten your question.

Comment: what is a "correct" json? can you give expected output?

Comment: I added expected JSON as Update 1.